# problem with constraint order in create table in livesql

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

This gives error:

```
Create table alpha
  (keycol varchar(1)  primary key not null, pi float(10) not null ,
   evalue float(10)  not null default 2.7182 );
```

This doesn't:

```
Create table alpha
  (keycol varchar(1)  primary key not null, pi float(10) not null ,
   evalue float(10)  default 2.7182 not null );
```

Why?

Comment: What error?? [Edit] to quote it in full.

Comment: Simply because that's how the syntax is specified. https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/, the <default clause> comes before the <column constraint definition>.

Comment: Why? Because that's simply how the database you are using defined the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each DBMS defined it's syntax to write SQL. It only works if you obey their rules. It's kind of obeying the law of a country while you are in it. You can't ask why I should do that? You have to. Or choose any dbms you like.

If your dbms tells you to follow this syntax

```
Create table alpha
  (keycol varchar(1)  primary key not null, pi float(10) not null ,
   evalue float(10)  default 2.7182 not null );
```

then you just have to.